# how to remove an element from a list typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Im using Angular 6, I have list and Im exporting it to CSV file using [Angular5-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular5-csv), I want to remove the last column of the list i.e., the last element of each array in the list. my list looks like

```js
let traceslist = [
{
  "name": "abcd",
  "email": "abcd@example.com",
  "decision": "yes",
  "userid": "abcd"
},
{
  "name": "phill";
  "email": "abcd@example.com";
  "decision": "yes";
  "userid": "phill";
},
{
  "name": "raj";
  "email": "raj@example.com";
  "decision": "no";
  "userid": "raj";
},
{
  "name": "john";
  "email": "john@example.com";
  "decision": "yes";
  "userid": "john";
}
]
```

now, I want to remove the elements userid, so that the column will not be present in my csv file, from the list. I have tried using splice but that was not successful.

It'd be great if anyone of you can help me with this.

Comment: The values in your (key,value) pairs should be in string form, and should end with a coma, not a semi colon.

Comment: Sorry, it was a firebase list which i could not copy paste here, so i made a sample here and missed adding quotes, that was my mistake sorry and Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.map` array method to remove the userid from every item in your array.

```
traceslist = traceslist.map(item => {
  delete item.userid;
  return item;
});
```

*By the way, it's not angular related so your title and tag is a little misleading. An array is the same in pure javascript.*

Comment: Thanks, it worked.. Actually it is a firebase list and im using angular so i kept title as angular. Sorry for misleading

Answer (score 2):

You can't use delete to remove an item from an array. This is only used to remove a property from an object.

You should use splice to remove an element from an array:

```
deleteMsg(removeElement:string) {
    const index: number = traceslist.indexOf(removeElement);
    if (index !== -1) {
        traceslist.splice(index, 1);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple javascript problem. Also you need to convert your data to string.
See the example below:

```js
let traceslist = [
  {
    'name': 'abcd',
    'email': 'abcd@example.com',
    'decision': 'yes',
    'userid': 'abcd'
  },
  {
    'name': 'abcd',
    'email': 'abcd@example.com',
    'decision': 'yes',
    'userid': 'abcd'
  }
];

traceslist.forEach( item => delete item.userid );
console.log(traceslist);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use  **.map()** method to achieve this

```js
let traceslist = [
    {
        name: 'abcd',
        email: 'abcd@example.com',
        decision: 'yes',
        userid: 'abcd',
    },
    {
        name: 'abcd',
        email: 'abcd@example.com',
        decision: 'yes',
        userid: 'abcd',
    },
    {
        name: 'abcd',
        email: 'abcd@example.com',
        decision: 'yes',
        userid: 'abcd',
    },
    {
        name: 'abcd',
        email: 'abcd@example.com',
        decision: 'yes',
        userid: 'abcd',
    }
]

    const result = traceslist.map(o => {
        delete o.userid;
        return o;    
    })

    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your JSON format is wrong, semicolon (;) is first and the strings should be in quotes check it below

```js
let obj = [{
    name: "abcd",
    email: "abcd@example.com",
    decision: "yes",
    userid: "abcd",

  },
  {
    name: "abcd",
    email: "abcd@example.com",
    decision: "yes",
    userid: "abcd",

  },
  {
    name: "raj",
    email: "raj@example.com",
    decision: "no",
    userid: "raj",

  },
  {
    name: "john",
    email: "john@example.com",
    decision: "yes",
    userid: "john",

  }
]

let filtered = obj.map(item => {
  delete item.userid;
  return item;
});
console.log(filtered);
```